# Python Word Count of a file using ssh from 100 machines

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, paramiko

I tried to write a word count code for give file. When I run this I get a empty in my dictionary, I am just trying to get only the words and its frequency. I am not sure where this is wrong.

```
import collections, re

class Wordcount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.freq_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)

    def count(self,input_file):
        with open(input_file) as f:
            for line in f:
                words = line.rstrip().strip().split()
                for word in words:
                    word = word.lower()
                    word = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9]+",'',word)
                    self.freq_dict[word]+=1
        print self.freq_dict

def Main():
    c1 = Wordcount()
    c1.count('out.txt')
```

my out.txt is  like this

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

--
 asd
 asdasd


The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog's

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

The space before asd to gets parsed in to the dictionary.

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'': 1, 'brown': 3, 'lazy': 3, 'over': 3, 'fox': 3, 'dog': 2, 'asdasd': 1, 'dogs': 1, 'asd': 1, 'quick': 3, 'the': 6, 'jumps': 3})
```

Also I want to scale this piece for ssh into nearly 1000 machines and reading the files and incrementing the frequency of the word. Whats the best approach ? Should i create a thread T1 for logging into machines and passing the login to another thread for reading the file and then pass on to another thread for incrementing the hash values alone.

Any suggestion on how to scale this is really helpful ?

Comment: Map / Reduce technique?

Comment: Ya, Its MR job, but i just want to use Python!!

Comment: Tip for avoiding blank lines: Check if line is not empty. And just strip is enough, remove rstrip.

Comment: Better use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for counting. For splitting create iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here simple example that uses [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). Fabric is framework that allows execute commands on multiple machines over ssh.

```
from fabric.api import task, run, get
from collections import Counter
from StringIO import StringIO


def worlds(data):
    return data.split()


@task
def count_worlds():
    s_fp = StringIO()
    # for big files better read to temp file
    get('/some/remote/file', s_fp)
    world_count = Counter(s_fp.getvalue())
    # do something with world_count
```

To execute this script on many machines just save it to fabfile.py and execute:

```
$ fab count_worlds -H host1,host2,host3
```

You may also define hosts in fabfile, for more info see [this](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/usage/execution.html#hosts).
And of course you should install fabric first.

Comment: Thanks! This is absolutely what I was looking for.